# Same openssl app behaves differently depending on platform

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, wireshark

I have an app that uses openssl to connect to a server on a different machine. In one case on my Ubuntu machine the app has no problem getting a secure connection. But when I recompile the same app for a target embedded board and run it I get this error:

```
# ./client3 192.168.1.99
Enter PEM pass phrase:
connecting to 192.168.1.99:16001
** client3.c:77 Error connecting SSL object
1024:error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature:rsa_sign.c:278:
1024:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:s3_clnt.c:2004:
```

The app uses the same private key and certificate in both cases.

As a test I used s_client on both platforms to see whether it's a problem with the app, and it too fails with the same error on the embedded target but makes a connection on the Ubuntu machine....just like the app.

Something I observed on a wireshark trace is that depending on what platform the app is running on, in the 'Client Hello' exchange the app advertises a much smaller set of cipher suites on the Ubuntu machine than on the embedded target app. Consequently the server chooses a different cipher suite in both situations. This puzzles me and not sure if it's related to my problem.

Worth noting the version of openssl on the Ubuntu machine which is the platform that works, is older than the version for the embedded target board.

Not using TLSv2.

Appreciate any help or a nudge on how to debug this.

Comment: Version of OpenSSL on both machines would be very helpful .

Comment: @MKAROL - Ubuntu machine is 0.9.8k, embedded board is 1.0.2h

Comment: It is something about the length of key or with the key itself [sources](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c#L276). For more information you could use some flags for [s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) like -state, -debug, -msg, -showcerts. **If you will edit your question with data from debug remember to remove sensitive data (eg. private key).**

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turned off compiler optimizations which resolved the issue.